# Tab bar brings me back to default tab when I'm on another tab?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I open the app and I click on a tab, the tab bar brings back to the default tab once and then if i click again on another tab the problem doesn't happen. it only happens once in the apps lifecycle?

Comment: Please provide your sources.

Comment: I believe it's a bit hard to help you if you don't provide any code of your problem :)

Comment: Can you show some code you've tried

Comment: here is the source code: https://github.com/DevstormApps/Friender/blob/events/Friender/Controller/MapVC.swift

Comment: this is the tab that when I click on it brings me back to the default tab once

Comment: this is the default tab: https://github.com/DevstormApps/Friender/blob/events/Friender/Controller/EventsVC.swift

Comment: @mbm Please paste the relevant code in your question instead of linking to an external repository.